# The type 'IConnectionFactory' exists in both Apache.NMS.NetCore and Apache.NMS

Tags: c#, .net-core, activemq-classic

I'm trying to create an `ActiveMQ` program in Visual Studio using .NET

In order to use ActiveMQ I installed these nuget packages:

Apache.NMS -Version 1.8.0

Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ -Version 1.7.2

Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetCore -Version 1.7.2

I really have no idea what the difference is between them.

This program is just an experiment on how to send push messages using ActiveMQ, so I'm just trying to create a small .NET Core console app.

I get this error:

> The type 'IConnectionFactory' exists in both Apache.NMS.NetCore and Apache.NMS

How do I know which one I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the `Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ` and `Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetCore` is that the later one is specifically made for applications using the .NET Core famework, which is different from the .NET Framework. For .NET Framework applications you use `Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ`.

So depending on if you are using the "normal" .NET Framework or .NET Core you will have to remove one of the two.

Comment: Then it means i can uninstall the Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ nuget?

Comment: @YonatanNir Correct

Answer (score 1):

Apache.NMS.Core is not the official nuget package , you should remove it and stick with Apache.NMS only which is the [official](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.NMS/) one